# How to access OrbitControls in html file?

Tags: three.js, orbitcontrols

In my simple html file I have this to use three.js functionalities:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
```

Now I want to use OrbitControls which is not part of three.js standard library it seems.I am not able to find it in three.js website.

What's correct way of using it?

Comment: The [Installation] guide explains the import of examples/addons with ES6 syntax. https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Answer (score -1):

1. download the OrbitControls.js and use
   `<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>`
2. use npm three and
   `import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'`